# What does Frank Moses say to Sarah Ross in Chinese?

Tags: dialogue, red

In the movie [*R.E.D.*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1245526), when they figure out a clue refers to the Library of Congress, Frank Moses reveals to Sarah Ross that he speaks Chinese by saying a phrase.

I *keep* hearing the last word as "[kumquat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumquat)", and -- by the nature of the movie -- guess that it's some kind of joke.

Unfortunately neither I nor anyone I know speaks Chinese, and I could find no reference online.

What is it that Frank Moses says?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the movie "R.E.D." Frank Moses (Bruce Willis) is saying the Chinese sentence "Years ago I used to live in Wuhan." His pronunciation is, of course, not the best, but if you speak Chinese and listen to the sentence several times, you will be able to understand it.
Even if you do not speak Chinese at all, you can understand the last word of the sentence, which is "Wuhan". 
I also found a source, which seems to confirm my translation, but is German though:
http://german.china.org.cn/culture/txt/2015-07/01/content_35952335.htm

Answer (score 5):

Based on *[Reddit sources](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/15sgm0/in_red_2010_what_is_frank_moses_willis_saying/)* and a *[blog](http://lifelittlesurprises.blogspot.in/2010/11/movie-date-red-retired-extremely.html)*, he spoke **gibberish**

> One of the funny thing in the movie was when Frank Moses (Bruce Willis) spoke in 'Chinese'. My friend is Chinese and he laughed. When I asked him what did he say, he said, "It doesn't mean anything, that doesn't even make sense."
>
> What he says actually doesn't translate into anything in English, so he's just trying to sound Chinese.

Comment: Disappointing...

Comment: The reddit guy agrees with you... :D